# Count row that have value in two separate columns

Tags: excel, function

So i'm trying to count who sold something at the end of the day doesn't matter how many item that person sold.

```
Name     Shoes      Shirts      Hat    
A                     1          2
B          1
C                     1           3
D          1          1
E
```

So if A sold then should count as 1 person sold something
If E is not selling anything that not count as anything

Comment: Sorry here is the picture of the excel... didnt know i cant type excel in post

http://i579.photobucket.com/albums/ss231/eviltommyng/excal_zps2h9he0fw.png

Comment: where do you want to write count values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example spreadsheet with data from `C6` through `F10`:

```
  |  C |  D |  E  | F |
5 |name|shoe|shirt|hat|
6 | a  |  1 |  1  | 0 |
7 | b  |  0 |  1  | 0 |
8 | c  |  1 |  1  | 0 |
9 | d  |  1 |  1  | 0 |
10| e  |  0 |  0  | 0 |
```

You could use this formula on the data example above: 
`=SUM(IF($D$6:$D$10+$E$6:$E$10+$F$6:$F$10>0,1,0))`

but you have to hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter (because it is an array formula).  You will know you did this correctly because it automatically adds { } around the formula, so it will look like this:

`{=SUM(IF($D$6:$D$10+$E$6:$E$10+$F$6:$F$10>0,1,0))}`

What this formula does:

`IF(D6+E6+F6 > 0, 1,0)` for each row until `10+E10+F10`, which leaves you with either a 1 or 0 for each row; 1 if the sum of the row > 0 and 0 if it was not > 0. It then adds up the info and gives you a count of any rows that had at least 1 sale of either a shoe, shirt or hat.

Comment: At first, yes, it does count the total products sold, but then it asks "Is that total products sold  greater than 0?" and if the answer is yes, then it counts that row as 1, if not, it counts that row as 0. Then at the end, it adds up all the rows that had at least 1 sale. So the final result is not a count of products sold, but it is a count of how many people sold at least 1 thing.